# If an elements style.left reaches something, change style.left to something else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, side-scroller

I'm currently working on creating a simple interactive CV, with mainly javascript. The idea is that the user steers a character to the right and then a few "about me"-divs will show up. These "about-me"-divs are supposed to move when the character moves, so it looks like they're getting closer to/further away from them. If unclear, check the [demo](https://willen17.github.io/Interactive-CV-github/).

I've fixed this by setting style.left to 100, and then subtracting from it each time the character moves to the right. In the example I've used minions, instead of "about-me"-divs, just to get the function to work.

```
let moveMinion = 100; // This is the same as their 'left' in CSS.
let moveMinionTwo = 150;

if (keyPresses.ArrowRight) {
        moveMinion -= 0.3;
        moveMinionTwo -= 0.3;
        
        minionOne.style.left = moveMinion + '%'; // I Used % because I want it to work on different screen widths.
        minioneTwo.style.left = moveMinionTwo + '%'; }
```

However I want the "about me"-divs to "repeat" and come back again, after the character have walked for a bit. Like this [example](https://vivirenremoto.github.io/mariocv/).

I tried using this code underneath, in the same function ofc, but nothing happens, except it seems like the minion blinks quickly when style.left is -10%.

```
if (minionOne.style.left <= -10 + '%') minionOne.style.left = moveMinion + '%';
```

TLDR: I want style.left to change to something else when style.left hits a specific number.

Bear in mind, this is not finished yet, so you don't have to judge the code and the project outside of the one I need help with, unless you want to give any tips.

[Repo on github](https://github.com/Willen17/Interactive-CV-github)

[My demo](https://willen17.github.io/Interactive-CV-github/)

Comment: You can not do less than with a string and expect it to work how you expect it. You need to get the numbers and compare that. Why are you not using the moveMinion value?

Comment: Oh alright, that makes sense actually. Thanks! I guess you're asking why I'm not using it inside the paranthesis? If I do that I will have to make a new variable and use in the end?  Like this? ' const minionStartValue = 100; if (moveMinion <= parseInt(-10) '%') minioneOne.style.left = minionStartValue;

Answer (score 0):

You can't `<=` strings.
You gotta convert one to a number and compare to a number.

```js
const threshold = -10;
const asNum = Number(minionOne.style.left.split('%')[0]);
if (asNum <= threshold ) {
  minionOne.style.left = `${100 + asNum - threshold}%`;
}
```

Comment: Okay, makes sense, thanks! How do I combine this with moveMinion++; in the first codeblock in my post? I'm not really familiar with the Number, split and `$ syntax.

Comment: I don't see `moveMinion++` anywhere. About my answer, the docs are here: [Number function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#function_syntax), [String split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [Template literals ($ syntax)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)